# JS while loop doesnt stop at true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, console, prompt

When you run this script it shows the HP for both of the pokemon when you press 1 and click enter it subtracts your attack hit points to the enemies hit points. When you or the ememy hits 0 or less than 0 hit points it is supposed to stop and just show who won in the console log. Instead it takes an extra hit to for it to show the message.

So if you are at -10 hp it takes one more hit.

```js
let firstFight = false;

while (!firstFight) {
  let fightOptions = prompt("1. Fight, 2.Items, 3.Potions " + wildPokemon[0].name + ":" + wildPokemon[0].hp + " " + pokeBox[0].name + ":" + pokeBox[0].hp);
  if (fightOptions == 1) {

    if (!firstFight) {

      if (wildPokemon[0].hp <= 0) {
        console.log("You have won!");
        firstFight = true;
      } else {
        let attack1 = wildPokemon[0].hp -= pokeBox[0].attack.hp;
        console.log(wildPokemon[0].hp);
      }

      if (pokeBox[0].hp <= 0) {
        console.log(wildPokemon[0] + " has killed you");
        firstFight = true;
      } else {
        let attack2 = pokeBox[0].hp -= wildPokemon[0].attack.hp;
        console.log(pokeBox[0].hp);
      }
    }

  } else if (fightOptions == 2) {

  } else if (fightOptions == 3) {

  } else {

  }

}
```

Are there any ways I can make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the points are getting subtracted after you check if they are equal to or below zero. Here is a way you can check before:

```
let firstFight = false;

while (!firstFight) {
  let fightOptions = prompt("1. Fight, 2.Items, 3.Potions " + wildPokemon[0].name + ":" + wildPokemon[0].hp + " " + pokeBox[0].name + ":" + pokeBox[0].hp);
  if (fightOptions == 1) {
    wildPokemon[0].hp -= pokeBox[0].attack.hp;

    if (wildPokemon[0].hp <= 0) {
      console.log("You have won!");
      firstFight = true;
    } else {
      console.log(wildPokemon[0].hp);
    }

    pokeBox[0].hp -= wildPokemon[0].attack.hp;
    if (!firstFight && pokeBox[0].hp <= 0) {
      console.log(wildPokemon[0] + " has killed you");
      firstFight = true;
    } else {
      console.log(pokeBox[0].hp);
    }
  } else if (fightOptions == 2) {

  } else if (fightOptions == 3) {

  } else {

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you dawg. I am working on a pokemon game. After v1 is done im gonna add in HTML and CSS then for v3 im gonna do some nodejs so people can sign up and save the info on a database.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add another if condition to check whether life of the player is still greater then '0' or less then '0' in the same turn like this.

in this way you don't have to go for next turn to check for the players life plus it rids off the extra conditional statements...

```
    if (fightOptions == 1) {

       let attack1 = wildPokemon[0].hp -= pokeBox[0].attack.hp;
       console.log(wildPokemon[0].hp);
       if (wildPokemon[0].hp <= 0) {
          console.log("You have won!");
          firstFight = true;
       }

      if (!firstFight){
         let attack2 = pokeBox[0].hp -= wildPokemon[0].attack.hp;
         console.log(pokeBox[0].hp);
         if (pokeBox[0].hp <= 0) {
            console.log(wildPokemon[0] + " has killed you");
            firstFight = true;
         }
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

While loops stops when the condition is false, in you case, you set it to not false, it is not stopping because you did not explicitly determine it. There are 2 ways you can do.

1st:

while(!firstFight == false)

2nd:

var firstFight = true;
while(firstFight)
then set the firstFight to false inside your if else statements.

Comment: while loop will only work if its condition is true. i think in this case it is no problem as while(!firstFight) will result "true"  and hence the loop will run until the value of "firstFight "  is set to "true" inside the loop, which in next iteration condition check while(!firstFight) will result "false" and hence loop will not run....